# How TO serve Map tiles from a database using Leafletjs

Tags: database, leaflet, tiles

Leaflet js requires the following tile source format:

http://localhost/tileserver/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

How can I serve tile images from a database instead of file system using Leafletjs
(and ASP.net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works very fast and seamlessly with Leaflet:

Apparently Leaflet just uses the z,x,y place holders to request specific tiles.

How you generate and return the tiles is very flexible indeed

```
L.tileLayer('**http://localhost/tileserver/tile.aspx?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}**', {
    minZoom: 7, maxZoom: 16,
    attribution: 'My Tile Server'
}).addTo(map);
```

where **Tiles.aspx**

```
Option Strict On

Partial Class tile
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim z, x, y As Integer

        z = CInt(Request.QueryString("z"))
        x = CInt(Request.QueryString("x"))
        y = CInt(Request.QueryString("y"))

        Dim b() As Byte = DB.GetTile(z, x, y)

        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Charset = ""
        'Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.ContentType = "image/png"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & y & ".png")
        Response.BinaryWrite(b)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End Sub
```

Comment: please share knowledge if u know....z is for zoom but what zoom does in leaflet js? when we specify url localhost/tileserver{z}/{x}/{y}.png for loading tile image then what z does? anyone can elaborately explain the meaning of z/x/y ?

Comment: sorry do not understand `z between 4 and 23 ` discuss in such way i could understand what z or zoom usage in leaflet. what is the utility of z?

Comment: z defines zoom level, the higher values are the higher zoom level

Comment: why do no say why zoom level require ? what zoom level does ?

Comment: i saw when we generate tile with 5 zoom level then 5 parent folder is getting created.

Comment: do you have your own tiles?

Comment: i have generated tile by a program.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write a server application that reads a request URL, pulls tiles out of a database, and delivers them over the web. JavaScript does not read directly from databases.

Comment: Thanks, but I came up with a good solution. Leaflet simply specifies z,x,y to request a specific tile. You can return that tile as you chose. see my supplied answer below.

Comment: @tmcw i guess u should discuss the db table design.