# How to create tile images for leaflet and save/load from database

Tags: leaflet

I am new to leaflet and like to know how to create a tile of images.

Leaflet js requires the following tile source format:

```
http://localhost/tileserver/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

What is `{z}/{x}/{y}`, and what kind of data should be stored in `z`,`x` and `y`?

Also, how do you store the image path in db?

I found one link with some information:

[How TO serve Map tiles from a database using Leafletjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732790/how-can-i-serve-tile-images-from-a-database-instead-of-file-system-using-leaflet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z/x/y is the [slippy map tilenames](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) format: zoom, column, and row of gridded tiles on multiple zoom levels. Tiles - square images representing parts of a map - are stored in this system. There are many ways to create tiles which [you can find by googling](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=leaflet%20create%20tiles).

Comment: thanks for answer. have u work with leaflet js. i like to know How can I serve tile images from a database ? any idea would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: z is for zoom but what zoom does in leaflet js? when we specify url http://localhost/tileserver/{z}/{x}/{y}.png for loading tile image then what z does? anyone can elaborately explain the meaning of z/x/y ?

Comment: @Thomas when  you browse google maps you have a zoom level - this is the same thing. Zoom (Z) implies the scale of the projection, it typically runs from z=4 to z=21.larger z implies zoom-in smaller z implies zoom-out