# how to Implement Caching for a Database Driven Map-Tile Server?

Tags: asp.net, caching, leaflet

How may we implement caching for a database Driven Map-Tile Server?

The ideas i have are:

1) cache responses (bytes) for unique z-x-y requests in memory (this will not scale well, if we have a large map area)

2a) render requested tiles to file system as `/site/tiles/z/x/y.png` and server from there subsequently,

2b) apply suitable `caching headers` to ensure `HTTP 304` for re-requests

I had implemented this basic map-tile server with [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com) and a simple ***.aspx page*** - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29741624/44080).

Each request for a map-tile hits the db, pulls out a binary-tile-image and returns a `.png` file like so:

**MapTest.html**

```
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([8.2, 6.95], 7);

L.tileLayer('**http://localhost/tileserver/tile.aspx?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}**', {
    minZoom: 7, maxZoom: 16,
    attribution: 'My Tile Server'
}).addTo(map);
</script>
```

**Tiles.aspx**

```
Option Strict On

Partial Class tile
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim z, x, y As Integer

        z = CInt(Request.QueryString("z"))
        x = CInt(Request.QueryString("x"))
        y = CInt(Request.QueryString("y"))

        Dim b() As Byte = DB.GetTile(z, x, y)

        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Charset = ""
        'Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.ContentType = "image/png"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & y & ".png")
        Response.BinaryWrite(b)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End Sub
```

Please how can we improve this with an effective caching?

Comment: There are too many solutions. Off-the-shelf proxy-like caching mechanisms like squid and mapproxy, ram-based caching, proximity-based metatile prefetching... It will all depend on where your bottleneck is.

Comment: @IvanSanchez yes there are several caching solutions, but which is most appropriate for a Map-Tile Server, which renders tiles from a DB?

Comment: It depends. Where is your bottleneck?

Comment: @IvanSanchez at present, i have not added any caching. I see requests for the same tile being repeated over and over again...i feel this can be improved with some (caching?) mechanism

Comment: Do not *"feel"*. Monitor your servers, measure where's your bottleneck, improve that. Otherwise you'll be a victim of premature optimization.

Comment: If the problem is "the same client is requesting the same tile over and over again", then cache in the client.

Comment: If the problem is "different clients are requesting the same tile over and over again", put a caching proxy.

Comment: If the problem is "the same tile is requested from the database over and over again", then cache database results.

Comment: Do not *"feel"*, do not solve problems you don't have, and do not optimize prematurely. Measure, find bottlenecks, fix those bottlenecks.

Comment: @do not "feel" -- true, but even looking at your existing design you can preempt possible bottlenecks by doing things intelligently

Comment: the 3 caching options you mentioned are all viable and may be combined to give a "balanced solution" - this is not premature